# Parsing nested yml file at second node

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml

I have the following yml file:

```
     Contours count: 8
     Contours:
             -
           Name: MI
           Count: 28
           Points:
               -
               x: 1116.
               y: 687.
               -
               x: 1.1224088134765625e+003
               y: 680.5911865234375000
               -
```

I have the following c++ code, under Qt, and opencv 2.3.1:

```
cv::FileNode Points = fs["Contours"];
if (Points.type() != cv::FileNode::SEQ)
    ui->textEdit->append("is not a sequence! FAIL");
cv::FileNodeIterator it = Points.begin(), it_end = Points.end();
int idx = 0; int Count = 0;
std::vector<uchar> lbpval;
for( ; it != it_end; ++it, idx++ )
{
    Count += (int)(*it)["Count"];
    QString s = QString::number(Count);
    ui->textEdit->append(s);
}
```

I walk until Contours go to Count, iterate them, and find the total sum, but i am stuck at the Points node. How can i parse this node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for( ; it != it_end; ++it, idx++ )
{
    Count += (int)(*it)["Count"];
    QString s = QString::number(Count);
    ui->textEdit->append("Count: "+s);
    ui->textEdit->append("-");
    cv::FileNode Points = (*it)["Points"];
    cv::FileNodeIterator it = Points.begin(), it_end = Points.end();
    int idx = 0; int x = 0; int y = 0;
    for( ; it != it_end; ++it, idx++ )
    {
        x = (int)(*it)["x"];
        y = (int)(*it)["y"];
        points_xy.x = x; points_xy.y = y;
        QString s = QString::number(x);
        QString t = QString::number(y);
        ui->textEdit->append("x: "+s);
        ui->textEdit->append("y: "+t);
        ui->textEdit->append("-");
    }
}
fs.release();
```